# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'chat' ошибка в Python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Я пытаюсь перенести функции из голосового ассистента в бота для телеграмма. В итоге я вообще не могу понять что это за ошибка, и что её вызывает - `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'chat'` Помогите плиз

пока отлавливал ошибку, понял что проблема в этой строке - `await commands[key](args)`

Полный текст ошибки:

```
ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-9' coro=<Dispatcher._process_polling_updates() done, defined at C:\Users\hybas\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py:409> exception=AttributeError("'list' object has no attribute 'chat'")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/hybas/Desktop/umorist/bot_new.py", line 50, in search_for_definition_on_wikipedia
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Начинаю поиск информации о " + search_term + " на википедии")
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'chat'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/hybas/Desktop/umorist/bot_new.py", line 68, in execute_command_with_name
    await commands[key](args)
  File "c:/Users/hybas/Desktop/umorist/bot_new.py", line 59, in search_for_definition_on_wikipedia
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "ошибка, БЗЗ")
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'chat'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hybas\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 417, in _process_polling_updates
    for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
  File "C:\Users\hybas\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 238, in process_updates
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "C:\Users\hybas\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "C:\Users\hybas\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 259, in process_update
    return await self.message_handlers.notify(update.message)
  File "C:\Users\hybas\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "c:/Users/hybas/Desktop/umorist/bot_new.py", line 75, in get_message
    await execute_command_with_name(command, command_options)
  File "c:/Users/hybas/Desktop/umorist/bot_new.py", line 70, in execute_command_with_name
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "ошибка, БЗЗ")
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'chat'
```

Сам код:

```
import logging
import string
import bs4
import random
import logging
import wikipediaapi
import webbrowser
import traceback

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

bot = Bot(token='токен')
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

#ответ на команды
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def begin(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет")

@dp.message_handler(commands=['bot'])
async def begin(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "На месте")

@dp.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
async def get_message(message):

    message = message.text.split(" ")
    command = message[0]
    command_options = [str(input_part) for input_part in message[1:len(message)]]

    async def search_for_definition_on_wikipedia(*args: tuple):
      if not args[0]: return

      search_term = " ".join(args[0])

      # установка языка (в данном случае используется язык, на котором говорит ассистент)
      wiki = wikipediaapi.Wikipedia("ru")
      
      # поиск страницы по запросу, чтение summary, открытие ссылки на страницу для получения подробной информации
      wiki_page = wiki.page(search_term)
      try:
          if wiki_page.exists():
              await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Начинаю поиск информации о " + search_term + " на википедии")
              # чтение ассистентом первых двух предложений summary со страницы Wikipedia
              await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, wiki_page.summary.split(".")[:2])
          else:
              # открытие ссылки на поисковик в браузере в случае, если на Wikipedia не удалось найти ничего по запросу
              await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Информация о " + search_term + " не была найдена")

      # поскольку все ошибки предсказать сложно, то будет произведен отлов с последующим выводом без остановки программы
      except:
          await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "ошибка, БЗЗ")

    commands = {
    ("wikipedia", "definition", "about", "определение", "википедия", "информация", "информация о"): search_for_definition_on_wikipedia,
}
    async def execute_command_with_name(command_name: str, args: list):
      for key in commands.keys():
          if command_name in key:
              await commands[key](args)
          else:
              pass  # print("Command not found")

    await execute_command_with_name(command, command_options)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
message = message.text.split(" ")
```

Вот это превращает message в обычный list. А у него нет атрибута `chat`.

Лучше копируйте полный текст ошибки. И сами смотрите на этот текст. Там как правило указывается номер строки и код, который это исключение вызвал.

Comment: я добавил полный текст ошибки

Comment: Спасибо, что навели на ошибку, я бы сам и не догадался

Comment: @LZLZZ Отлично. Вам надо работать с типом данных Message и не менять его в list.

Comment: Я уже сделал, спасибо. Ввёл новую переменную, и теперь использую её вместо message